# Callback function after javascript print dialogue?

Tags: javascript, css, printing

So I have a page with a lot of text and a table on it for example.

I want users to be able to print just the table with a 'print this table' javascript link, but I still want the rest of the page to be printable via the normal browser print method.

So to start with I have a print.css stylesheet included as below:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/print.css" media="print">
```

In print.css I have a class '.noPrint' set to display: none.

It seems to me that the solution is to wrap the content that is not a table in divs with a 'tempNoPrint' class, and on clicking the 'print this table' have javascript add 'noPrint' to all of the divs with 'tempNoPrint' thus hiding them in the printer version.

That's fine and I'm sure would work well.

However, how do I go about removing the 'noPrint' class from all the 'tempNoPrint' divs **after** the printing of just the table is done? Is there a javascript callback sent from the print dialogue? I could use a timer but it seems that would be very unreliable.

Comment: Have you tried removing the noPrint class after sending the data to the printer? I don't think you need a callback here.

Comment: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/printElement

Comment: Thanks Chibuzo, how silly of me! I tried that and it works! I've added a full answer.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, but for what I'm doing I wanted to keep the header and footer of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was overcomplicating the issue!

I wrapped all the content on the page that I didn't want to print with the button divs with a 'noPrintCustom' class, then I call this function:

```
var printCustom = function() {

    $('.noPrintCustom').addClass('noPrint');
    window.print();
    $('.noPrintCustom').removeClass('noPrint');
}
```

Thanks to all that helped!

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit of a nuclear approach but what I've done previously when tripping over this sort of thing is to output the bit I want to print to a hidden iframe and printing that.

```
//build new document
var code = "<!doctype html><html><head>";

//add in CSS needed by the table
code += "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='table.css' /></head><body>";

//get and add in table code
var code += "<table>"+document.getElementById('some_table').innerHTML+"</table>";

//finish up new doc code
code += "</body></html>";

//write new doc to hidden iframe (name: hiddenFrame)
var doc = hiddenFrame.document.open("text/html","replace");
doc.write(code);
doc.close();

//print
hiddenFrame.print();
```

Comment: Thanks Mitya, but because I wanted to keep the header and footer of the page intact and insert a lot into the 'head' tag to support this, I found it tricky getting this to work properly.

Comment: Nice little snippet for future desperation : )