# Window.print() error in IE in res://ieframe.dll/preview.js

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, window

`Onclick` of a anchor tag i am giving `window.print();` call and I get the print pop-up. But on the click of print I get the following script error.

```
An error occurred in the script on this page.
Line: 2115
Char: 1
Error: Your file waiting to be printed was deleted.
Code: 0
URL : res://ieframe.dll/preview.js
```

*Do you want to continue with the script on the page(yes/no buttons)*

May what ever you click Yes/No I don't get the print or in IE8 i get a blank print.

Firefox prints fine. But, fails in IE9.

Can some one help me on this one??

Comment: Do you want to post some code? Windows.Print is supported by all major browsers. Post some code.

Comment: Please provide your code which executes JavaScript, it's impossible to guess what is wrong.

Comment: Very, very long discussion about the same problem: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieitprocurrentver/thread/7e4156be-590d-42df-b393-dc95160cb2ff

Answer (score 6):

You can also get this error in IE10 if you are calling `window.close()` immediately after `window.print()`, especially if your DOM is large. My guess is that the page has not finished rendering when IE10 executes the `window.print()` call.

You can therefore get around this issue by:

- Calling `window.close()` within a hover event on the page. A print dialgue will steal the user's focus, so the hover event wont fire until the user has finished dealing with the dialogue. We found this to be the best solution.
- Not calling `window.close()` at all for IE10 clients
- As `window.print()` does not have a callback, calling `window.close()` after an arbitrary delay. I wouldn't recommend this as it will be unreliable
- Go "nuclear" with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10026995/228770), which loads the html into a hidden iFrame before printing, sidestepping the need to call `window.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this two Microsoft help articles:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973479
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2652062

At least it seems to be a problem with print driver and or problems with add ons installed in the IE. An other solution is to be uninstall IE 9 and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing/upgrading the printer driver on the server end, removing the printer on the desktop client and recreating the printer via the handy UNC path (double \ which doesn't show here) \server\printer" add method.